# Remove Clearch search/NetSpark from search engine

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, search

I installed a Chrome extension called "ESafely". It uses Clearch powered by NetSpark for the search engine (when you type in the address bar in Chrome. I originally wanted it so that when I'm on Facebook the porn won't show. I like it for the Facebook feature, but I don't want it for the search engine feature.

When I went into the Chrome settings to change the search engine, it still showed Google as my default. So I'm at a loss as to where to go to change this. It doesn't even show ESafely or Clearch or NetSpark in the list of search engines.

I know Firefox has an about:config feature, where you can put that in the address bar and tweak whatever you want. I found that Chrome as an about:about feature and an about:flags feature. But I can't find anything useful within these to manually change the search engine settings within chrome.

Does anybody have any ideas? I really don't want to get rid of esafely. I have OpenDNS running, and it works really great, but I didn't want to block Facebook all together so I installed easafely and it blanks out (just shows a white spot where it should be) the offending picture. Which is great!

*UPDATE* I installed the extension in Firefox to see if I could disable it there, and I noticed that it did the same thing. It showed Google as the search engine, but it still searched through Clearch. And then I noticed something else. It actually DOES search with Google, but then it does a page redirect and redirects my search to Clearch. I noticed this because it lagged for a second in Chrome. The Google search page came up first, and then it changed to the Clearch search. If anybody can figure out how this is working and how I can change it, that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I went to settings, and then click on "extensions" located in the left panel, then un-check the enabled box to disable it.